# Is this the right forum for web development & design?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I have just asked a question on web dev at ProWebMasters StackExchange regarding  [Internet Explorer CSS issues](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/internet-explorer-css-issues-on-site).

I'm not sure which is the right forum for web dev & web design?

Also if anyone can help with my xbrowser IE css issue I would be very grateful.

Comment: Don't confuse Stack Exchange sites with forums; down that way lies madness.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your question at ProWebmasters, I'd say SO is your best bet for that question.  Your question kind of boils down "this control (code) is borked; how do I fix it?"

This is the snippet that led me to the "my code is broken" conclusion, which is what makes it a candidate for SO.  Searching for "css slider" on SO returned several thousand results.

> The main errors I have presently is the slider on the template pages is displaying too far to the left and on the blog page the header is not displaying properly in IE.

For future questions, Programmers *does* handle some web design questions, but they are intentionally more conceptual broad brush stroke design type questions.  For example you could look at [css](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css).

Answer (score 0):

There is a stackexchange site for web development: [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). This is intended for issues around building and managing websites as well as related tasks. For questions that are more code-oriented, a better place to look and ask would be [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).